# Google and Dynamic javascript Drop Down menus

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, google-ranking

I have created a Javascript Drop Down menu that dynamiclly creates the drop down menu from JSON upon loading the web page. however I have been asked weather google ranking would be affected by this. all links for the Drop Down menu are not applied to the page if Javascript is disabled.

Question is: will Google ranking be affected by this Javascript drop down menu?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is an SEO issue, but there are techniques to get Google to crawl your content, such as using url hashes.

See:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992
http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-to-allow-google-to-crawl-ajax-content
http://www.techwyse.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/let-google-crawl-your-ajax-based-content/

Comment: thank you for replying, however I don't think I was clear enough. the links in the drop down must not be crawled, as such having a JS drop down would the ranking of the page still be affected?

Comment: Why not just use: <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">

Comment: Becuase we want the pages in the site to be followed except the drop down links. the dropdown is to be implemented site wide.